# Getting the integer value from enum

Tags: c#, enums

I am working on a basic [Battleship game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_%28game%29) to help my C# skills.  Right now I am having a little trouble with enum. I have:

```
enum game : int
{
    a=1,
    b=2,
    c=3,
}
```

I would like the player to pass the input "C" and some code return the integer `3`.  How would I set it up for it to take a string var (`string pick;`) and convert it to the correct int using this enum? The book I am reading on this is bit confusing

Comment: It is bad practice to use enums with underlying types other than `int` and `int` is the default, so you don't need to make it explicit. Just saying.

Comment: isn't your question "get the enum value from an string"?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Just parse the string and cast to int.

```
var number = (int)((game) Enum.Parse(typeof(game), pick));
```

Comment: I see a similar effect with the (int)(game)pick expression

Comment: What is `pick` here?

Answer (score 15):

```
// convert string to enum, invalid cast will throw an exception
game myenum =(game) Enum.Parse(typeof(game), mystring ); 

// convert an enum to an int
int val = (int) myenum;

// convert an enum to an int
int n = (int) game.a;
```

Answer (score 7):

just typecasting?

```
int a = (int) game.a
```

Comment: No - this isn't what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not sure that the incoming string would contain a valid enum value, you can use Enum.TryParse() to try to do the parsing. If it's not valid, this will just return false, instead of throwing an exception.

jp

Answer (score -1):

The answer is fine but the syntax is messy.

Much neater is something like this:

```
    public DataSet GetBasketAudit(enmAuditPeriod auditPeriod)
    {
        int auditParam =Convert.ToInt32(auditPeriod) ;
```

Comment: Not what the OP is trying to solve. Here you are passing in an Enum and converting it. The syntax has to be 'messier' as the OP is converting from a string to the Enums integer counterpart.