# Convert Enum value to integer in "Enum" and "Enum Class"

Tags: c++, enums, enum-class

What is the difference between the Enum and Enum Class and how to converting Enum value to the integer in "Enum" and "Enum Class"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the integer value from enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963993/getting-the-integer-value-from-enum)

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius No, that question is about C# enums.

Comment: No, my question is about difference between enum value and enum class value in c++.

Answer (score 4):

C++ has two kinds of enum:

enum classes
Plain enums
Here are a couple of examples on how to declare them:

```
 enum class Color { red, green, blue }; // enum class
 enum Animal { dog, cat, bird, human }; // plain enum
```

What is the difference between the two?

enum classes - enumerator names are local to the enum and their values do not implicitly convert to other types (like another enum or int)

Plain enums - where enumerator names are in the same scope as the enum and their values implicitly convert to integers and other types

in the Enum:

```
enum type{x=10, y, z=50, j};

int value = x;
```

in the Enum Class:

```
enum class type{x=10, y, z=50, j};

int value = static_cast<int>(type::x);
```

Comment: The second example should be `int value= static_cast<int>(type::x);`

Comment: Note that the underlying type defaults to `int` in 'scoped enumerations', unless otherwise specified explicitly such as `enum class myEnum: int64_t {...}`. See the [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

Answer (score 2):

As of C++23 there's a library function, `std::to_underlying`, for converting enum class values to their underlying value.

```
int main ()
{
    enum class Foo {a, b, c, d, e, f};

    return std::to_underlying(Foo::f); // returns 5
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PE35eq78j

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_underlying